# How do I limit the number of messages in my SQS queue?

Tags: amazon-web-services, message-queue, amazon-sqs

I want to have only 200 messages there.

All others should move to the dead letter queue.

We just don't have the capacity to process more messages due to dependency on other services.

Comment: I don't understand the problem, here... at all.  If you don't have the resources, right now, to service messages in the queue, then don't read from the queue until you do.  That's sort of the point of a queue -- holding work until you're able to process it.  Throwing work into the dead letter queue, "for later," you proposed, seems unnecessary.  Just read from the queue as slowly as necessary to stay within the constraints of the foreign system... What am I missing?

Comment: Can you please provide more information about how you send the information to the "3rd party service"? Does that service 'pull' from the queue, or do you have a process that retrieves data from the queue and 'pushes' it externally? Is there some way you can see whether the external service is 'ready' to receive more requests?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is possible to limit the number of messages in a queue. You can set a limit to the size of a message in a queue but not the number of messages.

Source: [SetQueueAttributes](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_SetQueueAttributes.html)

Answer (score 2):

You definitely can't limit the number of messages in the queue.

What is the nature of your application? Maybe there is a better solution if we knew more about why you need to limit the queue size...

Comment: The message is processed by calling another 3rd party service as part of the processing. That 3rd party service cannot process more than 20 requests at a time. Therefore there is no point trying to scale my services. I will just throw the extra load in the dead letter queue for later.

Answer (score 2):

SQS does not have such a limiting feature.

So don't try to do it at the SQS level. Instead, implement this limiting logic as you're pulling messages from the queue.

Keep track of the messages you pull from the queue and send to the 3rd party service. Once you hit your limit (of 20?), then junk the message.

1. Have a counter of messages that are "being processed".
2. Pull a message from the queue.
3. Check the counter and if it's less than 20, increment the counter and send the message to the 3rd party service.
4. When the 3rd party service call returns, decrement the counter.
5. When you check the counter in #2 above and it's 20, then junk the message.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**:

If you don't have a delayed visibility set to them, you could call `ApproximateNumberOfMessagesVisible` via the [cloudwatch](http://aws.amazon.com/documentation/cloudwatch/) API before allowing the message to go through.

> The number of messages available for retrieval from the queue.
>
> Units: Count
>
> Valid Statistics: Average

If you do have delayed visibility greater than `0`, you could do two checks, the second with `ApproximateNumberOfMessagesNotVisible`.

If this solution doesn't work, yes, this seems a bit much, but you could do a call on `NumberOfMessagesDeleted` and `NumberOfMessagesSent` and get the number of messages still in the queue.

So the (pseudo) *"code"* would look like:

```
if (ApproximateNumberOfMessagesVisible < 200)
    //Send message

//OR

var x = NumberOfMessagesSent - NumberOfMessagesDeleted;

if (x < 200)
    //Send message
```

[HERE](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/MonitorSQSwithCloudWatch.html) is the documentation of the above calls

**Information Check?**

**After a second look, I do not believe the below configuration will solve this problem. I will leave it in the answer until confirmed incorrect.**

I believe this is possible during the set up process by adjusting the `Dead Letter Queue Settings`

In the SQS set up you will see: `Use Redrive Policy` that states:

> Send messages into a dead letter queue after exceeding the Maximum Receives.

And just below that: `Maximum Receives` that states:

> The maximum number of times a message can be received before it is sent to the Dead Letter Queue.

This setting should send all overflow to a secondary queue that is an optional value. So in other words, you can enable `Redrive Policy` leave `Dead Letter Queue` blank with the `Maximum Receives` set to 200

[amazon-web-services](/questions/tagged/amazon-web-services) [amazon-sqs](/questions/tagged/amazon-sqs) [amazon-cloudwatch](/questions/tagged/amazon-cloudwatch)

Comment: And how would that allow me to limit he messages to 200.